# Why don't i have the "Respawn where you died" option when i die?

Tags: torchlight-2

Everytime i die i only have the **"respawn in town"** and **"respawn at the beginning of the dungeon level"** options, but  never the **"respawn where you died"** which would respawn you right next to your dead body. From what Iv'e read on internet other people have that third option and my friends have it as well, so why don't i?

**Additional info:**

I am playing Veteran difficulty, if that makes any difference.
I provided a screenshot that shows i don't have option to respawn here even when i die in an area where you can cast town scrolls,send pet to town and i should have enough gold for it.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [forum post](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=35656), you only get that option on "Causal" or "Normal".